# Adding php within a return statement

Tags: php, functions, theme-development

How should I add php code within a return statement. My following code does not work:

```php
function read_more() {
return '<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read More</a>';
}
```

Comment: Where is this being called, and why?

Comment: Where is this being called: functions.php.
Why: so I can have a custom "read more" button in post excerpts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just call PHP functions directly. In this case however we possibly don't want to call [`the_permalink()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_permalink/) since it echoes out the link:

```
function the_permalink( $post = 0 ) {
    /* ... */
    echo esc_url( apply_filters( 'the_permalink', get_permalink( $post ), $post ) );
}
```

whereas we want to return the link in a string. So your options are:

1. do use the_permalink(), but [capture the output buffer](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) to get the echoed link URL:

   ```
   function read_more() {
       ob_start();
       the_permalink();
       $permalink = ob_get_clean();
       return '<a href="' . $permalink . '">Read More</a>';
   }
   ```
2. or replicate the filter and escaping from the_permalink in your own code, saving it in a variable to use:

   ```
   function read_more() {
       $permalink = esc_url( apply_filters( 'the_permalink', get_permalink(), 0 ) );
       return '<a href="' . $permalink . '">Read More</a>';
   }
   ```
3. or just use [get_permalink()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_permalink/) instead, unfiltered, which is what a lot of WordPress's own code does (sometimes without escaping too):

   ```
   function read_more() {
       return '<a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '">Read More</a>';
   }
   ```

(As an aside, if you were doing this in a plugin or theme you were distributing you'd also want to make 'Read More' translatable, e.g. `'<a href="' . $permalink . '">' . __( 'Read More' ) . '</a>';` )